# Upstart script for nodejs daemon in CentOS doesn't work (crashes on start)

Tags: node.js, centos, daemon, upstart

I have the following in a .conf file in the /etc/init/ directory of my CentOS server:

```
#!upstart
description "shortnr server for fmc.io"
author      "Felix Milea-Ciobanu"

start on startup
stop on shutdown

respawn
respawn limit 10 30

script
    export HOME="/root"
    exec /usr/local/bin/node /var/www/fmc.io/nodejs/app.js >> /var/www/fmc.io/logs/shortnr.upstart.log 2>&1
end script

pre-start script
    echo "[`date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3NZ`] (sys) Starting" >> /var/www/fmc.io/logs/shortnr.upstart.log
end script

pre-stop script
    echo "[`date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3NZ`] (sys) Stopping" >> /var/www/fmc.io/logs/shortnr.upstart.log
end script
```

It's a pretty simple and straight forward upstart script. I named this service `shortnr`, after the nodejs software that the script starts up.

At the command line if I type in `start shortnr` I get something along the lines of `shortnr start/running, process 28350`.

However, I can't seem to access the nodejs server; If I do `ps aux | grep shortnr` at the command shell, nothing comes up.

If I do `stop shortnr` after running start, I get `stop: Unknown instance:`, meaning that the original service never started up.

The log file that I setup in the Upstart script looks something like this:

```
[2012-10-05T17:00:17.174Z] (sys) Starting
[2012-10-05T17:00:17.181Z] (sys) Starting
[2012-10-05T17:00:17.190Z] (sys) Starting
[2012-10-05T17:00:17.197Z] (sys) Starting
[2012-10-05T17:00:17.204Z] (sys) Starting
```

Basically the script is trying to start multiple times a second when I issued the start command, meaning  that the service must be crashing on start or something and trying to respawn?

However, if I copy the command after `exec` and paste it in the shell prompt, the nodejs script starts up and runs properly.

So that means something must be wrong with my Upstart script.

If I try start/stop the service with the `initctl` command, I get the same results.

I'm running CentOS 6.3 and Upstart 0.6.5

Anyone have any idea what could be causing this or how to fix my script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I couldn't figure out the answer to my problem, I just ended up using forever instead: https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever-monitor

Answer (score 0):

I am also running into similar problems on CentOS 6.3, Upstart 0.6.5 and Node.Js 0.10.5. I specifically upgraded Node so I could use the daemon module and be able to put the daemonized Node app under Upstart control.

Here's my /etc/init/job-worker.conf:

```
description "job-worker under Upstart/init control"

start on job-worker-start-event
stop on job-worker-stop-event

expect daemon

script
  #setuid myuser
  exec /root/BasicJobWorker/bin/basic-job-worker
  #sleep 5
end script

respawn
respawn limit 10 5
```

And here's my basic-job-worker script:

```
\#!/usr/bin/env node

// this code is run twice
// see implementation notes below
console.log(process.pid);

// after this point, we are a daemon
require('daemon')();

// different pid because we are now forked
// original parent has exited
console.log(process.pid);

var BasicJobWorker = require('../lib/basic-job-worker.js');

new BasicJobWorker().boot();
```

I have tried using "expect fork", "expect daemon" as well as no expect at all. In all cases the job is respawned too fast and it is eventually stopped.